# Populating array data from the Data Layer into GTM

Tags: google-analytics, drupal-7, google-tag-manager

I have a Data Layer that is giving me information like this from Drupal

```
dataLayer = [{
            "entityType":"node",
            "entityBundle":"article",
            "entityTaxonomy":
                {"funnel_path":{"2":"Find a Park"},
                "byline":{"4":"Name1","5":"Name2"}},"drupalLanguage":"en",
                "userUid":"1"}
        ];
    </script>
```

I can easily use GTM's Data Layer variable to pull in entity bundle. How do I set it to pull in the information in byline? I tried entityTaxonomy.byline , bu that give me an array. I can set to do entityTaxonomy.byline.4 to get Name1, but that would be silly since the editors would be regularly adding things.

I'd love any help on this!

Comment: This seems to be an object rather than an array. What do you expect as output ? Obviously you already know how to get properties from that object. Do you need all properties as a concatenated string, or the most recent entry (does not reliably work since object properties are not ordered), or ... ?

Comment: What do you except as output?

Comment: You can get byline object by entityTaxonomy.byline(not array) what else do you required ?